# default values from selected item before select item

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

I'm using ajax post method for send data in my php file. my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

ccc = jQuery.noConflict(); 

function getArticles(catid){
ccc.post('articles.php',{catid: catid},function(data){
    ccc('#articlediv').html(data);}

                );
             }

 </script>
```

and my select list this is:

```
 <select type="list" name="categorylist" onChange="getArticles(this.value)">
<?php 
 foreach($categoryid as $catid){

$title = modadcatarticlesHelper::getCatById($catid);

  ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $catid ?>"><?php echo $title ?></option>


 <?php } ?>

</select>
```

it's work and show result when select an item but my problem is i want show default items from a default selected item before select an item but my code only show result when select an item.
how can do it?

Comment: You mean you want to get the articles when the page loads?

Comment: yes i want get the articles when the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get something going you can simply add the following:

```
ccc(function () {//run after the page loads and jquery is ready

    getArticles(ccc("select[name='categorylist']").val());

});
```

I would advise you take care of your naming conventions `ccc` is not very readable and will make the code harder to understand.

Comment: Thank you dear Wilmer I add your code in my code but yet only when select an item show reult :(

Comment: Ok, are there other selects on the page?